# Entity Framework Core - manually assigning id's to linked entities

Tags: sql, .net, database, entity-framework-core

I've reviewed other related questions on StackOverflow, but I haven't found one that matches my exact question or scenario.

I have an JavaScript front-end where I have two entities that are linked, so in the front-end I have JSON objects that get 'linked' to each other like this:

---

**entity1**

name = "something"

entity2Id = 0

**entity2**

*1st record*

id = 0

name = "something else"

*2nd record*

id = 1

name = "something else again"

---

I then send the JSON to a .NET back end, and the idea is that as I'm manually specifying the primary key for entity2 and setting that as the 'foreign key' reference in my entity1, Entity Framework then somehow needs to generate a valid id for entity2, and maintain a reference to that id in the `entity2id` property of entity1.

I suspect I may be getting this all horribly wrong and that there's a fairly standard approach to achieving what I'm trying to do. What should I do to achieve the desired result? (I'm using a SQLite database, which probably doesn't make a difference.)

Comment: Actually PK value must be the CLR default (0) in order to be autogenerated. Hence you can't relate new entity2 to entity1 via entity2Id - the entity1 must contain reference to entity2.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks. So do you mean that in my JavaScript I would need an 'entity2' as a property of my 'entity1'? That doesn't match my structure as 'entity2' can't be a child of 'entity1'. The relationship is many 'entity1' to one 'entity2'.

Comment: Strangely that people refer to reference as "child", while in general it represents a "parent". Anyway, probably you should provide more context, e.g. the sample classes, the signature of the service method etc. But basically EFC requires objects, so either entity1 should have entity2 reference, or entity2 should have collection of entity1. After all, this is how EF models the relationships via navigation properties.

Comment: Ah not really - Entity1 can just have a foreign key pointing to an existing Entity2 and ef will figure out the rest. You don't need to have the whole Entity2 populated on Entity1. That's anyway the recommended approach. Not so sure about what OP wants though.

Comment: So @ChrisHalcrow you want: When saving Entity1 also create a new Entity2, OR:  When saving Entity1 you want to just assign an existing Entity2 to it? If the latter, then the problem is the Id = 0. EF will think it's a new entity and it will not work. Try assigning to Entity2 id = 1 and it should work as Ivan said in his comment.

Comment: Thanks @jpgrassi. The answer is kind of both! So Saving entity1 should create a new entity2 if it doesn't exist, but then a 2nd entity1 that references the same entity2 should reference the newly created entity2 using it's newly created database Id

Comment: OK @jpgrassi I can try assigning id's of 1 and 2 to my entity2 in the JavaScript and see if that works

Comment: Sure, you can for sure do that. Both cases are supported.. I'll try to write something up real quick :)

Comment: @Johnny did my answer help in anything?

Answer (score 1):

You have a `one-to-many` relationship there. To make it easier to explain I'll change your Entit1 to `Book` and Entity2 to `Genre`. So something like this:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use the FluentApi to configure the relationship (most importantly the FK key on `Books` from `Genres`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Genre)
        .WithMany(b => b.Books)
        .HasForeignKey(p => p.GenreId);
}
```

Now we can achieve your two scenarios:

1 - Create a new `Book` along with a new `Genre`

2 - Create a new `Book` that uses an existing `Genre` on db

```
var bookWithNewGenre = new Book
{
    Name = "Book 1",

    // Here we are creating a new Genre, without Id.
    // GenreId here will have the default value of 0, 
    // which EF will use to find out that it has to be created
    Genre = new Genre { Name = "Mistery"}   
};

var bookWithExistingFictionGenre = new Book
{
    Name = "Book 2",

    // Here we are specifying the GenreId = 1 which already exists in the Database
    GenreId = 1,

    // You don't need to set this to null
    // but I like doing it to make EF and my code clear that I'm using an existing Genre
    Genre = null
};

using (var context = new BookContext())
{
    context.Books.Add(bookWithNewGenre);
    context.Books.Add(bookWithExistingFictionGenre);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

After saving you'll have this in the database:

[image: Query result after saving]

You'll probably have to change your front-end to start sending also the `Genre` object along. In cases where it's a new one, the `Id` will be missing. When you serialize it into your c# types, you can figure it out if you have to create new instance or just maybe check if the Id front-end passed exists or not.

Remarks: I did all this using `Sqlite` and the EF core packages version `2.2.0-preview1-35029`.